# Error could not read Username for 'https://<gitlab.private.url>': No such device or address

Tags: git, ubuntu-16.04, tortoisegit, git-gui, rabbitvcs

after a long review & searching over google.
Finally, I came across the decision that none of the article/link could help me for find the issue.

Actually, I have installed `RabbitVCS` from its [official site](http://rabbitvcs.org/) as well follow the same steps which are mention over [here](http://rabbitvcs.org/).

The **intention** is to use such kind of tool as a ***SVN & GIT GUI client*** especially in `Ubuntu(16.04)  OS`. Our main concern is to get the same kind of *look & feel* as like "`TortoiseSVN` / `TortoiseGit`".

After an aforesaid installation process, I `restarted` my `system`.
and while I go for clone a repository from remote the following error message am getting,

[image]

Not sure how to come over this issue.... any help really *appreciative !!!*

> Ultimately I no longer be able to perform any single git
> operation(pull, push, clone, revert/discard, show log, diff...etc)
>
> Also, I have no idea about what am missing either in system > configuration level or at somewhere else ?
>
> It's weird for me that RabbitVCS
> don't ask for authentication/authorisation steps. so really get
> confused that from where its internally refering.

**NOTE -** Consider my system's OS is **Ubuntu 16.04 OS**(64-bit).

Comment: Are there any special chars in your name (or your password if you clone via https)?

Comment: @TimothyTruckle my user name contains dot(.) which is special char & obviously password contains too.

Comment: A dot should not be a problem, but you should avoid blanks and @.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Thanks for your quick response. there is not any blank and @ used.